# Choosing specific Lambda from within method

Tags: ruby, lambda, closures

Currently learning more about Lambdas in Ruby and came across an example like this which I found very interesting:

```
[106] pry(main)> def another_method
[106] pry(main)*   begin
[106] pry(main)*     lambda { return "Hello World" }
[106] pry(main)*   ensure  
[106] pry(main)*     puts "another_method exits"
[106] pry(main)*   end  
[106] pry(main)* end  
 => :another_method
[107] pry(main)> another_method
another_method exits
=> #<Proc:0x000001013d2af0@(pry):149 (lambda)>
[108] pry(main)> another_method.call
another_method exits
=> "Hello World"
```

Now my current understanding of this, is that the lambda gets executed, holds the value and only returns it when requested(.call)?

This leads me to the following question:

```
def some_method
  a =  lambda { return "hello" }
  b =  lambda { return "there" }
end
```

If you had the scenario above, is there a way that you could choose which one to call and get its value? Because I get the following if I simply do:

```
some_method.call => "there"
```

Any tips on that and if possible, would be great! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this example:

```
def some_method(n)
  a =  lambda { return "hello" }
  b =  lambda { return "there" }

  n % 2 == 0 ? a : b
end
```

You should get the following:

```
some_method(2).call
=> "hello"
some_method(1).call
=> "there"
```

I'll try to explain what I think you're missing:

In the code below, calling some_method will always return the value of `b` since it's the last line to execute. (The code in ensure in your other example does not count)

```
def some_method
      a =  lambda { return "hello" }
      b =  lambda { return "there" }
end
```

so when you do `some_method.call`, you're getting `b.call`

This is how my example illustrates choosing between lambdas =)

Comment: Thanks Abdo! I knew there was a trick I was missing there :-)

Comment: Sure thing! Enjoy Ruby! :-)